# Does WINAPI automatically free memory attached to controls?

Tags: c, winapi

Just a simple question about WIN32 api.
I have a function that connects to MySQL using the MySQL C API, and that retrieves a linked list of pointers to structs.

So in a dialog callback I fill a `ListView` control by these elements, and attach every element struct pointer to a row in `ListView`.

The question is: **should I free the pointers after removing all items from `ListView` by `LVM_DELETEALLITEMS` for example when I click a refresh button?

Or do the WIN32 API frees them for me?**

Comment: With the WinAPI calls, you are responsible for cleaning up resources attached to controls.

Comment: Thanks this is so precise and clear

Comment: Wanted to confirm are you really doing this in C and not C++? That's tough. In C you have to be even more meticulous with memory management.

Comment: Yes in C,  just cause I faced a segfault  double free or corruption I thought it was caused by the fact that winapi has freed the memory and I re-did it

Comment: WIN32 API can not free your allocated structs because it do not know how it allocated. so of course you must frees it yourself

Answer (score 5):

When deleting items from a list view, you are responsible for cleaning up any resources that are referenced through the *lParam* member of the [LVITEM](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774760.aspx) structure. The Windows API will not do this for you.

In fact, the Windows API cannot do this for you. It has no way of knowing, whether the pointer points to memory allocated using `new`, `malloc`, `IMalloc`, or any other allocator. Or maybe the pointer points into a statically allocated array, and doesn't need to be freed altogether. Or it may not even be a pointer, but rather a hash value for sorting, or an index into some other structure.

Since only you know, how to interpret the *lParam*, all responsibility with respect to resource management is on you. Contrary to [some opinions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41308490/does-winapi-automatically-free-memory-attached-to-controls#comment69820118_41308490), C++ will not help you here.